# ¿Por qué se usa "vosotros" en biblias latinoamericanas?

Tags: hispanoamérica, tiempos-verbales

#### Español

Creo que esta pregunta es más sobre español que sobre el cristianismo, así que la hago aquí.

Primero, ya sabemos que por lo general [no se usa *vosotros* en Latinoamérica](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13516/9309).  Pero las Biblias más populares en Latinoamérica son, sin duda, versiones de la [Reina Valera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reina-Valera), particularmente la de 1960, la cual [usa *vosotros* en vez de *ustedes*](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romanos+12%3A1&version=RVR1960).

Sé que hay algunas versiones modernas que usan *ustedes*, pero no son populares. ¿Por qué? Me parece raro que la mayoría de los cristianos latinoamericanos usen una Biblia que contiene formas que nunca dirían.  ¿Por qué no han cambiado a una traducción que use *ustedes*?

---

#### English

I believe this question is more related to Spanish than Christianity, so I'll ask it here.

First of all, we know that *vosotros* is generally not used in Latin America.  But, the most popular bibles in Latin America are easily versions of the Reina Valera, particularly the 1960 version, which uses *vosotros* instead of *ustedes*.

I know that there are several modern versions that use *ustedes*, but they aren't popular.  Why not?  It seems strange to me that the majority of Latin American Christians use a Bible that contains word forms that they would never speak.  Why have they not changed to a translation that uses *ustedes*?

Comment: porque la biblia es solemne y como cualquier texto solemne usa vosotros. Lo mismo aplica para las constituciones de los paises.

Comment: @MatiasAndina No creo que tenga que ver la solemnez con *vosotros*. Además, hablá por tu país porque en la constitución del mío no encontré *vosotros* en ningún lugar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In part, tradition. It's what people are used to hearing. To a large extent, consider the situation with English. Many people still use the KJV — it very nicely maintains distinction between singular and plural in the second person that are lost in modern translations and is still readily readable.

The *vosotros* use can provide a level of distinction, though different. For example, when Jesus broke bread with his disciples, if we hear "Tomad y comed", we infer a closeness (versus the distant *tomen y coman*) that would be lost in using only *ustedes*.

My church uses readings from an *ustedes* only bible, though the liturgy itself maintains *vosotros*, so this is mainly conjecture.

Comment: I agree that the KJV provides useful information to readers with the distinction between singular and plural, but I haven't seen any *vosotros* bibles distinguish between informal (vosotros) and formal (ustedes)... it seems like they always use vosotros.

Comment: Tomad y comed involucra más desapego que tomen y coman. Alguien que habla de vosotros, sobretodo si ese alguien es Jesús, tiene siempre un aura de superioridad (no necesariamente negativa)

Comment: Bible in English is capitalized when referring to any Christian Bible.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo, para mí vosotros suena más distante que ustedes además de que me parece un arcaísmo. Básicamente, todo depende de lo que a uno lo acostumbraron a escuchar o leer. Yo siempre leí la NVI, así que probablemente se deba en parte a eso

Answer (score 8):

**English**

This is a complex topic.  First off, there are reasons for the widespread use of RVR1960 in Latin America that have little to do with linguistic choices made in the translation.  Second, some of the translator's choices in other translations raise questions of orthodoxy.  Third, the plethora of multiple translations, such as we have in English, may be a function of wealth in addition to language choices.

Most Latin Americans have a passive acquaintance with *vosotros* usage even if they do not use that form in daily life.  This is especially true among those who read a lot.  Merely replacing *vosotros* with *ustedes* and making the verbs agree would add little value to an existing translation, and probably wouldn't be worth the cost.

I don't claim to be an expert on Christian orthodoxy, nor do I think this is the right forum to discuss it.  But I do want to mention in passing that RVR1960 gets good reviews among those who are concerned with such matters.  That's not to disparage any other translation.

In my own experience, I carried a parallel bible Spanish-English to an English speaking Bible study for years.  I found that RVR1960 was closer to ESV or NKJV than NIV was to either of those two, despite the linguistic differences between English and Spanish.  I attribute this to the choice of manuscripts available to translators in the 1500-1600 time frame, when both the KJV and the original RV were produced,  versus the choice of manuscripts available today.  There may be other reasons.

Finally, producing a new translation is an expensive proposition.  The money available for that purpose is probably better used elsewhere.  One such use is producing audio bibles for hundreds of new world languages that have no system of writing.

**Español**

Este tema es complejo.  En primer lugar, hay razones por la aceptación de RVR1960 que tienen poco que ver con las alternativas lingüísticas escogidas.  En segundo lugar, la presentación en algunas otras traducciones contraen dificultades de ortodoxia.  En tercer lugar, la plétora de traducciones que tenemos en el inglés puede ser en función de riqueza y no de alternativas lingüísticas.

La mayoría de los latinoamericanos por lo menos reconocen el empleo de *vosotros*, si bien no lo usan en conversación común.  Especialmente tratándose de personas que leen mucho.  El mero remplazo de *vosotros* con *ustedes* y el cambio correspondiente de los verbos no aportaría mucho valor a una traducción ya existente,  y probablemente no valdría el costo.

Ni pretendo ser un experto en ortodoxia cristiana ni pienso que se debería debatir en este foro.  Pero digo, de paso, que los que se ocupan de tales cuestiones dan una opinión favorable de la versión RVR1960.  Esto no es para descartar alguna otra traducción.

En mi experiencia propia, porté una biblia paralela, español-inglés a un estudio bíblico entre angloparlantes durante varios años.  Encontré que la RVR1960 se asemeja más a la ESV o a la KJV de lo que la NIV se asemeja a cualquiera de los dos.  Creo que esto se debe a los manuscritos disponibles en la época 1500 a 1600, cuando se realizaron las traducciones KJV y la RV original, en contraste con los disponibles hoy en día.  Pueden haber más razones.

Por último, la publicación de una nueva traducción es un proyecto costoso.  El dinero que se usaría sería más util en otro proyecto,  como la producción de biblias grabadas en idiomas del nuevo mundo que carecen de un alfabeto escrito.

[Disculpen los errores en esta traducción.  Mi español no es tan bueno como lo tenía pensado.]

Comment: A fascinating read.  (Even though I religiously avoid reading the bible, myself!) // A Spanish spell checker in your browser will be your friend.

Comment: I don't trust spell checkers.  I've been bitten too many times.  It would come as a surprise to me if my browser had a Spanish mode in the spell checker,  as well.

Comment: I use Opera, but there's an Opera extension that allows installation of Chrome extensions. I don't know if something like that that would work for you.  If not, the text can be run through a word processor with a spell checker.  If you want to try it -- there's no need to follow the spell checker's suggestion slavishly.  I like using it because it gives me a bit more confidence writing in my 2nd language. But it's your decision whether you want to use one.

Answer (score 5):

Tanto en América como en el sur de España se usa "ustedes" en lugar de "vosotros" en el habla coloquial. Sin embargo es un uso alternativo que da lugar a ambigüedades, que en textos como el Evangelio llegan a ser realmente inoportunas, sobre cuando se trata de citas. «Todavía tengo muchas cosas que decirles» (Juan 16:12): ¿a quién?, ¿a ustedes?, ¿a ellos?. Mucho mejor «Todavía tengo muchas cosas que deciros», en español genuino y claro. La riqueza de las variedades regionales no debe impedir el uso del registro culto de una de las lenguas más cultas de la humanidad.

Comment: Muy buen ejemplo, ¡gracias!